# Timeout requests but 200 with Cloudflare

Tags: nginx, okhttp, cloudflare

We have problems with timeout requests with Cloudflare. Please see example below:

1. OkHttp 3.6 + Retrofit 2.1 + Android +HTTPS + HTTP/2
2. Create an OkHttp client
3. GET (or POST) requests (loop, synchronous with 1 s between requests)

**device log**

```
GET test?id=0 200
GET test?id=1 200
GET test?id=2 200
```

**nginx log**

```
GET test?id=0 200
GET test?id=1 200
GET test?id=2 200
```

4. Bring the network down (we disconnect the cable but device is still connected to the router)
5. Wait for eg. 30-60 seconds

**device log**

```
GET test?id=3 timeout
GET test?id=4 timeout
GET test?id=5 timeout
GET test?id=6 timeout
GET test?id=7 timeout
GET test?id=8 timeout
GET test?id=9 timeout
GET test?id=10 timeout
```

6. Bring the network back

**first case (log from our nginx with cloudflare)**

```
[21/Feb/2017:13:45:49 +0000] "GET test?id=7 HTTP/2" 200 44
[21/Feb/2017:13:45:49 +0000] "GET test?id=16 HTTP/2" 200 44
[21/Feb/2017:13:45:49 +0000] "GET test?id=5 HTTP/2" 200 44
[21/Feb/2017:13:45:49 +0000] "GET test?id=4 HTTP/2" 200 44
[21/Feb/2017:13:45:49 +0000] "GET test?id=6 HTTP/2" 200 44
[21/Feb/2017:13:45:49 +0000] "GET test?id=8 HTTP/2" 200 44
[21/Feb/2017:13:45:49 +0000] "GET test?id=14 HTTP/2" 200 44
[21/Feb/2017:13:45:49 +0000] "GET test?id=10 HTTP/2" 200 44
[21/Feb/2017:13:45:49 +0000] "GET test?id=9 HTTP/2" 200 44
```

**second case (log from our nginx without cloudflare)**

```
[21/Feb/2017:13:45:49 +0000] "GET test?id=3 HTTP/1.1" 499 0
[21/Feb/2017:13:45:49 +0000] "GET test?id=4 HTTP/1.1" 499 0
[21/Feb/2017:13:45:49 +0000] "GET test?id=5 HTTP/1.1" 499 0
[21/Feb/2017:13:45:49 +0000] "GET test?id=6 HTTP/1.1" 200 0
[21/Feb/2017:13:45:49 +0000] "GET test?id=7 HTTP/1.1" 499 0
[21/Feb/2017:13:45:49 +0000] "GET test?id=8 HTTP/1.1" 499 0
[21/Feb/2017:13:45:49 +0000] "GET test?id=9 HTTP/1.1" 499 0
[21/Feb/2017:13:45:49 +0000] "GET test?id=10 HTTP/1.1" 499 0
[21/Feb/2017:13:45:49 +0000] "GET test?id=11 HTTP/1.1" 499 0
```

Request from 3 to 11 were timeout on device so why we get 200 on those requests when we use Cloudflare? If we make those requests directly to our server (without Cloudflare) we get 499 as expected.